# How to create custom action using SharePoint hosted app

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin, custom-actions, sharepoint-hosted-app, custom-action

Is it possible to create "**custom action**" under the "**Site Action**" menu in "**HOST WEB**" using SharePoint Hosted App.?
We do not want to follow the native method of packaging all the necessary files related to the custom action into a WSP and activate it with a help of a feature. We already have lots of features in our WSP.